# stop the Redirect from www.domain.com todomain.com

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I want to stop the Redirect from  [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) to domain.com
I need [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) " work only  no redirect "
and  domain.com " work only no redirect   >>   how do it? on htaccess with Cpanel**

Comment: How is the current redirect from www to non-www implemented? You need to change that; not implement another rule. Please edit your question to include the contents of your existing `.htaccess` file (if that is indeed where you have implemented this redirect). Although you also mention cPanel?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on a lot of factors. Some of the main ones are:

1. What kind of application do you use?
2. Do you have any Rewrite Rules inside your .htaccess?

The first one is important as some applications do require to be re-configured to work with the new URL, either "www" or "non-www".

Depending on your current .htaccess rewrite rules, you might want to add/remove rules to achieve that.

Certainly, your host should be able to also help with this one.